# Selection of Dryer-vent exhaust height

Tags: dryer

A stacked [washer dryer](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/3a/3a2f20cb-03f5-4442-9e94-3fa97fdeeb65.pdf) is to be retrofitted.  The [electric dryer](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/d1/d1548409-3af1-45e1-abba-efdae3bb9f7d.pdf) is to be mounted on top.  The wall behind the stack will be drilled so that a 4" dryer vent can be installed and vapor can be vented outdoors.

- [Dryer Manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/3a/3a2f20cb-03f5-4442-9e94-3fa97fdeeb65.pdf)
- [Washer Manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/1d/1d90b4de-ebaa-4d5f-a0cf-494bb1ffd212.pdf)

There is a set of outdoor stairs on the outside of the wall and the port would be under the landing of the stairs if it is drilled at 4 feet above ground.

[image]

The plan is drill the hole for the vent at 4 feet above the ground as shown in the photo.

Is there a requirement that the exhaust be at a higher elevation than dryer exhaust port?   If not, is the 4ft exhaust hole problematic, if the the dryer's exhaust port is at 5 feet?  What problems can be expected?

I would prefer the exhaust hole to be higher than the dryer's exhaust port, however, as you can see from the photo: I am certain that foot-traffic on the steps will eventually cause a problem with (damage to) the vent.

Comment: Usually the restriction on placement of a gas exhaust vent is that it can't be a certain distance from an opening into a home/building(doors, windows).  Other than that it will depend on the type of people near it(if you need to protect it from baseballs/bats, rocks, semi trucks).

Comment: Not answering the question, but maybe saving hassle later. Don't mount the dryer on top of the washer, but build a shelf for the dryer, leaving an inch or so between them. That way, when you need to remove the washer, the dryer doesn't need touching. Also may provide a small shelf! What material is the landing made from?

Comment: @Tim. Thank you for responding.  Interesting shelf suggestion.   The landing and steps are made of wood.  I have updated the post with a photo

Comment: Is it a gas(NG/propane) exhaust vent or just an electric dryer vent?

Comment: Whether it's code-compliant or not, I don't know, but from a practical stand point, venting warm, moist air directly under a wooden staircase and close to all the electrical work would cause me to pause. I can't offer a better solution, but you may want to give that a though.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for responding: it will be an electric dryer.  How does electric vs propane figure into decision making?

Comment: "dryer vent can be installed and **gas** can be vented outdoors." (emphasis added). Sure seemed like you were installing a gas dryer. Usually, the warm, moist air from a dryer isn't referred to as "gas". Technically, air is a gas, and the water vapor in it is also a gas, that's just not common phrasing in the US.

Comment: Gas exhaust has restrictions on how close it can be to house openings(CO poisoning).  Electric dryers only have the instructions on how far from the dryer you can go, placement is up to you.  Freeman does offer some good points.  Kind of a bad location, can't really go up since people will bang into it, and limited to the area of the landing to get away from the services.

Comment: In the future I will refrain from using "gas" so as to avoid confusion and use vapor.   Thanks for the constructive feedback

Comment: The manual states a maximum of 80 feet straight or 47 feet with elbows.  Vents should be kept as short as possible but you probably have some room to play with, but would try sideways or down before up(because of lint).